# What does // mean in a path?

Tags: command-line, paths

I was working in my terminal, when I misspelled while `cd` to root (`/`). Accidentally, I typed `//` and I got in terminal:

```
root@weblocalhost://#
```

When i type `pwd`, i get response `//` but when I type `ls -s` i got same list as in `/` directory.

When you type more than 2, i.e. `///` you get:

```
root@weblocalhost:/#
```

Always 1 `/` except for 2. Is there any difference and what is `//` for?

Answer (score 10):

`/` is equivalent to `//`

From [the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_267) (emphasis added):

> #### 3.267 Pathname
>
> A string that is used to identify a file. In the context of
>   POSIX.1-2008, a pathname may be limited to {PATH_MAX} bytes, including
>   the terminating null byte. It has optional beginning `<slash>`
>   characters, followed by zero or more filenames separated by `<slash>`
>   characters. A pathname can optionally contain one or more trailing
>   `<slash>` characters. **Multiple successive `<slash>` characters are
>   considered to be the same as one `<slash>`, except for the case of
>   exactly two leading `<slash>` characters.**

[And](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12):

> #### 4.12 Pathname Resolution
>
> ...
>   A pathname consisting of a single `<slash>` shall resolve to the root
>   directory of the process. A null pathname shall not be successfully
>   resolved. **If a pathname begins with two successive `<slash>` characters,
>   the first component following the leading `<slash>` characters may be
>   interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than
>   two leading `<slash>` characters shall be treated as a single `<slash>`
>   character.**

For a nice discussion of exceptions (cygwin and directories) see: [How does linux handle multiple consecutive path separators (/home////username///file)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file)

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple slashes to a directory and it will not change anything. E.g. these three commands all do the same:

```
cd /home
cd /home/
cd /home//
```

After any of these my current working directory is is set to /home (check with `pwd`).

I *guess* that you have your prompt configured to *do something smart* and that you ran into unanticipated behaviour.  What do you get when you `echo $PS1` ?

Check [this comment on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file) which may explain it.

Comment: My PS1 in bash on OSX is "\h:\W \u\$" and I get this strange behavior, too. / and /// and //// and ///// all show up as /, but the special case of two forward slashes shows up as two forward slashes.

Comment: I got the \u@\h:\w (<b>u</b>ser at <b>h</b>ost, <b>w</b>orking dir) in Ubuntu 12.10 but I fail to reproduce the problem.

Comment: no i get always // when checking pwd in any case. for echo $PS1 i get: \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$

Comment: I just manually set my PS1 and I can not reproduce it with **two** slashes. Weird. Not with 1, 3 or 4. Only with 2. I am at a loss to explain this.

Comment: Maybe this comment from unix.stackexchange is the answer:  *I believe  that Windows POSIX compat APIs will also treat //remote/... the same as the UNC path \\remote\... format. – Stephen P Jan 20 '11 at 0:39*