# What is the directory "//"?

Tags: command-line, directory, root

My teacher asked me why directory "`//`" (double-slash) exists.

I know that the // is the same as /.

I search for it and found many answers (// was created for compatibility with older Unix Systems) and other like (// is nothing and is just the /).

My teacher said that is all wrong.

So why // exists, what is the propose of having a directory that do the same as /?

Comment: Your teacher should provide bibliography to support that claim. On URIs the // [was a mistake of Tim Berners-Lee](https://www.zdnet.com/article/double-slash-in-web-addresses-a-bit-of-a-mistake/)

Comment: See also [What does // mean in a path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274510/what-does-mean-in-a-path) and [unix, difference between path starting with '/' and '//'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12283/unix-difference-between-path-starting-with-and)

Comment: Does the `//` directory exist, or is `//` just another way of typing `/`? `ls -ai /` It also removes concerns about "`/` termination" when `bash`ing together (constructing) a complex path. Typos from URIs, too.

Comment: I have tried that answers and it is all wrong. The directory // is the same as /. The question is why // exists, what is the function of that. The objetive on having 2 entries for the same thing?

Comment: I already tried that. And it is a wrong answer. He told me that I will never find this answer on internet.